# Maps SDK Encryption Compliance

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

A very quick question but does using the Google Maps SDK change my apps encryption compliance status? As in do I now have to answer yes when asked about the app containing encryption?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I have the app in internal testing at the moment but from my understanding export compliance is declaratory, it's just a popup that asks if encryption has been added to the app